# Button click event not fired in jquery modal popup

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have implent one jquery modal popup

**Jquery Code:-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
     $('#<%=a2.ClientID %>').click(function(){
     $('#modelPopup').dialog({
     title: "Add New Server",
     width:650,
     height:450,
     modal:true,
     buttons:{
      Close:function(){
      $(this).dialog('close');
      }
     }
     });
    });    
    })
    </script>
```

**Html:-**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAddNewServic" Text="Add Service" runat="server" 
 CssClass="btnSmall_bg_green" Height="26px" Width="98px" OnClick="btnAddNewServic_Click" />
```

**Code Behind:-**

```
 protected void btnAddNewServic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int rowCount = 0;
            rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["clicks"]);
            rowCount++;

            Session["clicks"] = rowCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
            {
                TextBox txtServerU = new TextBox();
                Label lblU = new Label();

                txtServerU.ID = "txtServerU" + i.ToString();
                lblU.ID = "lblU" + i.ToString();

                lblU.Text = "Service" + (i + 1).ToString() + ":";

                panelnewserver.Controls.Add(lblU);
                panelnewserver.Controls.Add(txtServerU);

            }
        }
```

I could not able to find the issue of this code. Can anyone help me to fire this button click event. Thanks in advance.

**Updated:-**

**JQuery Code:-**

```
$(function(){
     $('#<%=a2.ClientID %>').click(function(){
     var $dialog= $('#modelPopup').dialog({
     autoopen:false,     
     title: "Add New Server",
     width:650,
     height:450,
     modal:true,        
     buttons:{
      Close:function(){
      $(this).dialog('close');
      }
     }     
     });
      $dialog.parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
      return false;
    });    
    })
    </script>
```

Now the button click event is fired but after Complete my process the modal popup will be automatically closed. Can anyone help me to overcome this issue.

Comment: First I suggest to change $(function() {}); to be $(document().ready(function()});

Comment: Did you check in FireBug say, did click event really triggering?

Comment: @andrey.shedko $(function(){}) is perfectly fine to use and is just a shorter way of putting $(document).ready(function()

Comment: It's not always prefectly fine, because this may concern to page lifecycle.

Comment: @andrey.shedko you're wrong. Read it from jQuery if you don't believe me http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @mjroodt i was add $(document).ready(function() too but i button click event is not fired..

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean in your update? Are you not intending to automatically close the dialog when clicking the 'Add Service' button?

Answer (score 3):

From memory I believe jQuery UI dialogs actually take the dialog element out of its place in the DOM when they display them. Because this results in your `btnAddNewServic` being moved out of the `form`, your postback won't be triggered correctly.

So something like this might do the trick for your JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    var $dialog = $('#modelPopup');

    $dialog.dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: "Add New Server",
        width:650,
        height:450,
        modal:true,
        buttons:{
            Close:function(){
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });

    $dialog.parent().appendTo($("form:first"));

    $('#<%=a2.ClientID %>').click(function(){
        $dialog.dialog('open');
    });    
})
```

What this will do is add the dialog back into the form after it is created, so your postback should now run.

Comment: @dinesh.k Try this version.

Comment: it working for my logic but have one issue... I was use one black color background in behind the modal popup that background would hide my popup...

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons), the buttons should be in an array.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#<%=a2.ClientID %>').click(function(){
            $('#modelPopup').dialog({
                title: "Add New Server",
                width:650,
                height:450,
                modal:true,
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: "Close",
                        click: function(){
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
        });    
    })
</script>
```

Comment: his click event is not firing . I guess the point `button array` will come after that ?

Comment: The event is in the button array. so, possibly it is because of this.